# How to use putIfAbsent for when action returns Future

Tags: dictionary, caching, concurrency, dart, thread-safety

In my class I'm loading some files, and for efficiency I wanted to make a thread safe cache. I see in the map class that there is a `putIfAbsent` method, but it doesn't accept `async` types. Also not sure if this structure in general is safe to use.

This is the style of what I'm trying to do:

```
final Map<String, String> _cache = new Map();

Future<String> parse(final String name) async {
  _cache.putIfAbsent(name, () async { // this async is not allowed
    return await new File(name).readAsString();
  });
  return _cache[name];
}
```

Since I can use async on the parameter I've opted to use locks instead, but it makes the code far more verbose..

```
final Lock _lock = new Lock();
final Map<String, String> _cache = new Map();

Future<String> parse(final String name) async {
  if (!_cache.containsKey(name)) {
    await _lock.synchronized(() async {
      if (!_cache.containsKey(name)) {
        _cache[name] = await new File(name).readAsString();
      }
    });
  }

  return _cache[name];
}
```

Does anyone know how I can simplify this code, or if there are better libraries I can use for thread safe cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "this async is not allowed"? I see no particular issue with the `putIfAbsent` code, and I believe it should work.
The one probelem I see is that the cache is not caching futures, but strings. Since your function is returning a future anyway, you might as well store the future in the cache.

I would write it as:

```
final Map<String, Future<String>> _cache = new Map();

Future<String> parse(final String name) =>
    _cache.putIfAbsent(name, () => File(name).readAsString());
```

but apart from fixing the `_cache` map type, that is effectively the same, it's just avoiding creating and waiting for a couple of extra futures.

Comment: I meant that adding async to the lambda isnt allowed due to the method signature of `putIfAbsent`. Caching the future does seem like a pretty clean solution! Going to look into that!

Answer (score 2):

I've created an extension to support an asynchronous action for `putIfAbsent`:

```dart
extension MapUtils<K, V> on Map<K, V> {
  Future<V> putIfAbsentAsync(K key, FutureOr<V> Function() action) async {
    final V? previous = this[key];
    final V current;
    if (previous == null) {
      current = await action();
      this[key] = current;
    } else {
      current = previous;
    }
    return current;
  }
}
```

You can use like this:

```dart
final Map<String, String> _cache = {};

Future<String> parse(final String name) async {
  return await _cache.putIfAbsentAsync(
    name,
    () async => await File(name).readAsString(),
    // ^^^^^ this `async` is now allowed
  );
}
```